# Regex to validate linux filename (multi encoding)

Tags: php, linux, validation, encoding, localization

My setup is:
Fedora Linux / PHP / Apache

I have a requirement to allow the user to type a filename in their language.  Linux creates the file fine in arabic when I was testing.

My question is, what characters and therefore what regex should I be using to validate the filename?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but here's a tool I use a lot to try out and create regular expressions "in real time": http://rubular.com/

This question might be interesting for anyone trying to match Arabic chars in PHP: How can i Match arabic letters using regexp in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: POSIX allows all characters except

- `\0` (null char)
- `/` (path separator)

Anything goes, so it is really down to what *you* want to be accepting

If you want the filenames to be portable for Windows too, keep in mind:

- windows uses case-insensitive filenames
- [What makes a valid windows filename](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_dewey/archive/2004/01/19/60263.aspx)

Comment: Path separator is ok too, as long as it's escaped.

Comment: I'll play it safe and disallow the path separator as well.  Thanks

Comment: @Ben: sure, 2sec google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words; I found another interesting concept while scanning the actual POSIX:2008 standard: _[Portable Filename Character Set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)_ (from "4.7 Filename Portability"). Note that this is _not_ a POSIX restriction, but a recommendation for portability

Comment: I think you forgot about reserved filenames (".",".."), or can they somehow be used too?

Comment: @XzKto: mm. sort of a good point. However, they are really just filenames (actually directory entries that are hardlinks to the current dir/parent dir). So, yes they can be used, except for the fact that they always exist as directory entries. Note that `../something.txt` is ruled out anyways due to the the `/` char. I don't know whether there are reserved filenames on linux (would `/dev/null` count as a reserved name? On windows, `COM1:`, `NUL:`, `CON:` etc. _are_ reserved - see the linked article)

Comment: @sehe: I think you got that one wrong - they are not hard links, they are special directory entries: you can't remove/change them while you can remove/change normal hard links, you can't hard link directories in most linux distributions, and surely ".." will change it's link if you move directory that contains it while hard links change only if you move linked files. But that is besides the point, I was just wondering if there are more of that reserved names we should look after to make this answer better.

Answer (score 1):

All strings are valid, except 0x00. So instead of a regex, try:

```
if (strpos($filename,"\x00")===false) {

}
```

Comment: I think i'll be on the safe side and go with sehe and disallow the path separator as well.